# nusoap wsdl problem when moving to new server?

Tags: wsdl, nusoap

I am trying to move a file which calls a wsdl service with the nusoap class. On the new server i get the following error:

```
wsdl error: HTTP ERROR: Couldn't open socket connection to server http://ip...:xxxx/service.asmx?wsdl, Error (13): Permission denied
```

Is this an incorrect server setting? If so which setting would be the most common with this issue?
Could it be some kind of firewall? Should i ask my hosting company to enable something??

Any tips, suggestions??

fyi with $nusoapclient->debug_str i get

```
soap_transport_http: connect connection_timeout 0, response_timeout 30, scheme http, host xxx.xxx.xxx, port xxxx
```

soap_transport_http: calling fsockopen with host xxx.xxx.xxxx connection_timeout 0
 soap_transport_http: Couldn't open socket connection to server

Comment: btw don't yet know if this is the problem but how can one tell if your server is configured with permissive or enforced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for those running into the same issue, check if your php/apache config is permissive vs enforced. This  might solve your problem